# Quick-select contiguous subarray

Tags: ds.data-structures, sorting

Motivated by the question from this [blog post](http://11011110.livejournal.com/332617.html),
the following data structure question seems interesting and fun to me.

- Preprocess: A list of numbers $A = a_1,...,a_n$
- Query(s,t,k): Return the $k$-th rank element of the sublist $A[s:t]$ where $A[s:t] = a_s,...,a_t$.

There are two trivial solutions:

- Space = $n^3$, Time = $1$. Construct a look-up table
- Space = $n$, Time = $O(n)$. Do nothing for preprocessing. Quick-select the $k$-th element in $A[s:t]$.

Is there some non-trivial solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$O(n)$ space with $O(\log k/\log \log n+\log \log n)$ query time is possible. See [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2133099).

Answer (score 4):

When $k  = \lceil (s-t)/2 \rceil$, this the range medians problem. There are solutions which are much better than the two trivial ones: you can answer the first $q$ queries in time $O(n\log q + q\log n)$. I believe the algorithms can be adapted to arbitrary rank. References:

- [paper](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~muthu/medians.pdf) that defined the problem
- [best known](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.1761v1.pdf) algorithm
- an [improvement](http://sites.google.com/site/algoresearch/new.pdf) for $q = \Omega(n^2)$ queries

Comment: The link for "improvement" links to "http://file///Users/anikolov/Downloads/new.pdf", which is a file on your personal computer, not on the internet.

Comment: @jbapple fixed now

Comment: Now the link works, but it does not discuss the question.

Comment: @jbapple thank you! i am not sure where my mind was :) I think it should be ok now.